# Booting Ubuntu from a bootable USB-Stick

Tags: dual-boot

Hello I got an Ubuntu PC in my room but sometimes my brother uses it to play minecraft because our parents windows 7 PC does Not Support it  I want to Do Java programming on Ubuntu because i understand Ubuntu better than Windows I want to know if my already prepared bootable USB Stick is able to Boot not to install Ubuntu on my parents PC AND to Do Java Programming without touching my parents Windows Hard drive using only the USB Stick for saving Data and Files. Remember I only want to Do it in try ubuntu Mode instead of installing it.
Thanks for Help :)

Answer (score 0):

When you boot to the Live media, any changes you do will only be on the live media.  Writing would only go to any drive outside the live media if you specify by actually mounting it and specifically choosing that mount for output.

When you say you won't be installing on, I'm assuming you mean you won't be installing Ubuntu on the Windows machine's hard drive.  You might consider installing Ubuntu on a stick and booting to a fuller environment for programming.

Comment: Eh so I need one sitck for saving Data and anotherone for booting?

Comment: No you don't. Make a bootable Ubuntu USB with Mkusb. In my experience, that is the only app that has not failed me, in making bootable Ubuntu sticks. You simply choose the percentage of the remaining space of the USB for persistance and the rest will be formatted as FAT32, for user created files.

Comment: @DominiquetheGamer No.  I mean one stick for the full installation.  Of course you would need the Install stick or the install media.  But I install the full OS on a USB stick just as if it were a normal Hard Drive.  Then I boot to it.  When you boot to the install, it'll be no difference in appearance and functionality as booting to a regular hard drive.  The installation should be one stick just as a normal installation is one harddrive.